# Get next element of an array on each call to a function

Tags: c#

The program that i have is supposed to open one link at a time. The timer is set to 10secs. What I want it to do is call the `webBrowser1.Navigate(s[x]);` with different values of s[x] every time 10secs pass. I.e. on first Tick I want the s[0] to go to, s[1] when the second tick happens and so on till s[3], then back to s[0].

```
    private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string[] s = new string[4];

        s[0] = textBox1.Text;
        s[1] = textBox2.Text;
        s[2] = textBox3.Text;
        s[3] = textBox4.Text;

        webBrowser1.Navigate(s[0]);
    }
```

Comment: So what is your problem - your code does get "new" values when timer Tick happens...

Comment: no it doesnt, i want the s[0] to go to s[1] when the tick happens and so on, then back to s[0]...

Comment: Then stop passing it a hard-coded value of `s[0]`. :-)

Comment: yes i knew that, the main problem was i didnt know how to make it go back to 0.

Comment: I've inlined you comment... and removed some unrelated timer stuff... Feel free to revert if disagree.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just declare a field and [increment](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/36x43w8w%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) it each tick.

```
private int textboxNumber;

private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string[] s = new string[4];

    s[0] = textBox1.Text;
    s[1] = textBox2.Text;
    s[2] = textBox3.Text;
    s[3] = textBox4.Text;

    webBrowser1.Navigate(s[textboxNumber]);

    textboxNumber++;
    if (textboxNumber > 3)
        textboxNumber = 0;
}
```

This probably isn't the best approach to this problem, but it will give you what you want.

Comment: Agreed. Could move the string declaration and initialization out of the Tick though; all the Tick needs to do is call the Navigate command and increment.

Comment: Yup, but this is SO, not CR.SE :)

Comment: I'm not familiar with the acronyms you're using. Regardless, it was more of a style note for the question poster so that he can use it as reference.

Comment: SO = StackOverflow.com, CR.SE = CodeReview.StackExchange.com ;)

Comment: +1. also something like `textboxNumber = (textboxNumber+1)% s.Length` would be one line and not depend on hardcoding length of array in 2 places.

Comment: just a quick question is there a way to find out how many secs are left for the timer

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov Never seen that before, yet so simple.

Comment: and also array definition :)